# $A_5$ cannot have a normal subgroup of order $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove that $A_5$ cannot have a normal subgroup of order $2$

My  Attempt:

Suppose that $H$ is a normal subgroup of  $A_5$ and $|H|=2$ .

It can be shown that $H$ is contained in the center of A <sub>5</sub>  . So elements of $H$ commutes with every element of $A_5$ .

Say $(ab)(cd) \in H$ . Since every element of $H$ is in the center , 
$(ab)(cd)$ commutes with every element of $A_5$ .

But we can check that $(abc)(ab)(cd) \neq (ab)(cd)(abc)$ .

Therefore $A_5$ doesn't have a normal subgroup of order $2$.

Is this proof correct?

Can someone please provide some alternative proof for this question .

Comment: Looks ok to me. Depending on how many times it has been covered (and whether it happened in this course or on an earlier course) a teacher might want you to justify the step *It can be shown that ....* It does sound like this poses no problem to you.

Comment: Well, [that was easy](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/681834/11619) :-)

Answer (score 2):

> A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is normal if and only if $H$ is the union of conjugacy classes of $G$ (For proof, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175828/a-normal-subgroup-is-the-union-of-conjugacy-classes) link)

So computing normal subgroups in $S_n$ and $A_n$ are easy! Since elements of $S_n$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle type.

Comment: But there are a few subtleties (not really relevant here) when figuring out conjugacy classes in $A_n$ as opposed to $S_n$.